# How to show pop up dialog in any activity android

Tags: android, android-intent, dialog, popup

i am developing an android app in which i want to show popup dialog when notification receive for example i am doing this right now

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, Incomingcall.class);

         i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
         startActivity(i);
```

it works great but i want this functionality on popup dialog how i can acheive my task? any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a new method outside of `onCreate` and use `AlertDialog` inside to open dialog. And call that method where you want to open dialog.

```
   public void openAlert(){
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Really Exit?")
            .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, /*paste code what you want to do*/)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes,
                    /*paste code what you want to do*/).create().show();
}
```